# Having problems with Powershell ConsoleShell.Start

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-2.0

Running the following code resulting in an HostException;

```
  Public Sub RunPowershellInConsole(ByVal scriptText As String)
    Dim config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create
    Dim args() As String = New String() {scriptText}

    ConsoleShell.Start(config, "Windows PowerShell", "", args)
  End Sub
```

.

```
System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException was unhandled
  Message=The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred when retrieving handle for active console output buffer. Contact Microsoft Support Services.
  Source=Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost
  WasThrownFromThrowStatement=False
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleControl.GetActiveScreenBufferHandle()
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostRawUserInterface.GetBufferInfo(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO& bufferInfo)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostRawUserInterface.get_ForegroundColor()
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostRawUserInterface..ctor(ConsoleHostUserInterface mshConsole)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface..ctor(ConsoleHost parent)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost..ctor(RunspaceConfiguration configuration)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.CreateSingletonInstance(RunspaceConfiguration configuration)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Start(RunspaceConfiguration configuration, String bannerText, String helpText, String preStartWarning, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleShell.Start(RunspaceConfiguration configuration, String bannerText, String helpText, String preStartWarning, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleShell.Start(RunspaceConfiguration configuration, String bannerText, String helpText, String[] args)
       at MyApp.Barry.Bosely.RunPowershell.RunPowershellInConsole(String scriptText) in C:\Dev\MiscProjects\GordonB\Barry\Barry.Bosely\RunPowershell.vb:line 87
       at MyApp.Barry.Bosely.frmMain.TEstToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Dev\MiscProjects\GordonB\Barry\Barry.Bosely\frmMain.vb:line 119
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at MyApp.Barry.Bosely.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       Message=The handle is invalid
       NativeErrorCode=6
       InnerException:
```

Little help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried this code in my *Console Application* and it worked:

```
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using Microsoft.PowerShell;

namespace TryConsoleShell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            ConsoleShell.Start(config, "Windows PowerShell", "help text", new string[] { "-noexit", "ls" });
        }
    }
}
```

I guess your application is *Windows Application* and this scenario is either not supported at all or you still have to have a console window available (I have not  tried this way yet).

EDIT:

It worked in WinForm Application as well. But the console window is still needed for the console host. To make the console window available just change the project output type to *Console Application*.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.PowerShell;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            ConsoleShell.Start(config, "Windows PowerShell", "help text", new string[] { "-noexit", "ls" });
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I have never seen use of this scenario in practice and did not even know that it actually works. Are there some practically useful applications of it?

Comment: I hope so, but i need to see how the shell window handles scripts like set-executionPolicy unrestricted

Comment: If it's all about `Set-ExecutionPolicy` only then you can just avoid interaction by using the `-Force` switch: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`.

Comment: it's not all about that... we have other scripts where the user will want to see the output.... Cheers for the remote-signed -force.  +1 ;)